# desktop sharing using XMPP protocole

Tags: networking, desktop, xmpp, protocols, remote-desktop

Is it possible to use XMPP for a desktop sharing application ? is there any inconvenience ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, I guess it is possible to send the right information across. XMPP is called extensible because in a way it is. Basically XMPP allows you to send arbitrary XML to a receiver without the server needing to be configured to "accept that data". Only your clients need to be aware of it. It is not technically necessary to make/use an official extension.

What you would do would be to encapsulate [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc) or [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) packets into the XML payload of the xmpp messages. Probably encoding it in a CDATA section (most efficient). The main problem that you might have is latency caused by the messaging to be routed via the server.

Answer (score 2):

@dtb empathy/vino can do it on Linux with Telepathy

Comment: A standard Ubuntu installation with Empathy as XMPP client can share desktop sessions via XMPP. Since XMPP is working, you don't need to care about firewalls and locked ports.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such application: http://sourceforge.net/projects/remotevnc/

Answer (score 1):

There is no official [protocol extension (XEP)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/) for desktop sharing over XMPP,
and I'm not aware of any application offering desktop sharing over XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is! XMPP is an easy and extensible protocol, there are plenty of [libraries](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml) to work with.

Major considerations would be:

- Port and firewalls. Are any of the PC's locked down?
- Application permission. Do you need to run the client app with elevated privs to access functionality, like remote control and device accesibility?
- Multi-user. XMPP has group chat functionality, will that be used?
- Robust. You can send offline messages.

If you don't need remote-control functionality, but just an app to share a whiteboard, text editor or such, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing command-line of the Linux operating system trough xmpp you can use:

```
pigterm.sf.net
```

It also supports encryption.